# How to find man pages for specific git subcommands

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to find `git remote` command instructions. When I type `man git` , there are much informations. I need to read from the beginning.

Is there something like `man git push`, or `man git | grep -push`?

Still googling the efficient way to use `man` in terminal.

Comment: Try `man git-push`.

Comment: Solved,           `man git-remote`

Answer (score 0):

There is also `git help remote`

and `git remote --help`